# Подключение шаблонов в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, хук

Здравствуйте, мне нужно подключить некоторые категории (рубрики) в отдельные шаблоны.

Например у меня есть две категории с id 24 и 27 и я их хочу подключить в отдельные шаблонные файлы которые назвал features.php и portfolio.php пытаюсь подключить через function.php с помощью фильтра template_include, но почему-то не проходит проверка на тег-функцию is_category и не выполняется скрипт

```
    if (is_category(['24']) || is_category(['27'])){
    function my_template() {
        if( is_category( 27 ) ){
            return get_template_directory() . '/portfolio.php';
        }
        if( is_category( 24 ) ){
            return get_template_directory() . '/features.php';
        }
    }
    add_filter('template_include', 'my_template');
}
```

Но если убрать проверку `if (is_category(['24']) || is_category(['27'])){`
то в таком случае код срабатывает и подключаются нужные категории в нужных шаблонах, но при этом не работают остальные шаблоны сайта ни `index.php`, ни `category.php`, ни `single.php` ни любой другой.
И что странно если убрать проверку `if (is_category(['24']) || is_category(['27'])){` то код ниже отрабатывает и получается

```
if( is_category( 27 ) ){
   return get_template_directory() . '/portfolio.php';
}
```

этот код срабатывает хотя здесь такая же проверка `if( is_category( 27 ) )` ... В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы не учитываете [процесс загрузки WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Template_Actions). Код functions.php исполняется задолго до формирования главного цикла WordPress, а именно тогда устанавливаются переменные, которые способны "правильно ответить на вопрос" `is_category()`. Другими словами, во время выполнения вашего

```
if (is_category(['24']) || is_category(['27'])){
```

WordPress ни сном ни духом не в курсе, какие там категории существуют.

> но при этом не работают остальные шаблоны сайта

Естественно, потому что вы гробите шаблон, возвращая из своей функции null. [Читайте документацию](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/template_include).

В общем, надо так:

```
function my_template( $template ) {
    if( is_category( 27 ) ){
        return get_template_directory() . '/portfolio.php';
    }
    if( is_category( 24 ) ){
        return get_template_directory() . '/features.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'my_template');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ) Очень познавательно, да вот сказывается нехватка теории и практики с этой цмс, только взялся за неё  ))

Answer (score 0):

> которые назвал features.php и portfolio.php

Неправильно назвал. Нужно `category-{slug}.php` или `category-{id}.php`

См https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B8

И не нужно в коде никаких условий выбора рубрик.

Comment: Ну я вот уже так то и сделал по id, просто думал, что можно создавать шаблоны со своими названиями и потом их подключить от имени категории. Но вопрос остается открытым по поводу is_category(); Это нормально, что проверка не срабатывает в functions.php?

Comment: Выходит этой проверкой можно воспользоваться например в шаблоне category.php  и др, но не в functions.php?

Comment: @ПавелМуха и создавать шаблоны можно и проверять условия. Но всему своё место и правила. См документацию.